# How to watch for changes in firebase realtme DB

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I am developing an admin panel for getting requests from users about food order, so I want to get notifications whenever new order came. So the question is are there any ways to watch changes in DB and if there are , make notification(Snackbar)

Answer (score 1):

You can listen change with **value** event .
Read for more detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 1):

valueeventlistner will bring all the nodes again again once the DB is updated. To bring the lastly added node only, use below.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("YOUR-URL-HERE/PATH/TO/YOUR/STUFF");

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
    }
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

onChildAdded() will be revoked only for each of the new food order. You can use other methods as well, which will give you a good flexibility. Even an order is removed you can get it by onChildRemoved().